# How to add integer field to content type?

Tags: entities

I am trying to add  year field to content type. I selected integer as field type, then i see text field as widget. How can I set to 4 digits max and allows only numbers only?

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Date Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/date)

Then when you add a new field, select Date as your Field Type.

When you configure it use something like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a field validator.  There is a module for [Field Validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_validation).

Here is a nice tutorial on [number formats.](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/decimal-float-or-integer-in-drupal-fields/)

I'm curious why you are using Year as an integer type.  Did you try using the [Date Field Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/date)?

Comment: I thought date module requires me to enter entire date but i just need to enter 4 digits here. Will the date module allow me to enter just 4 digits year?

Comment: As for date module, if you do not care about the year as a date (ie. use other date related functions like calculating duration, range, etc.) then you should not store as a date.  You can always display just a date year though.

Comment: Here is another module to specify number formats: https://www.drupal.org/project/formatted_number or you can create a custom formatter.

Comment: Yes, when you configure a Date field there are settings for the granularity. You can choose to only allow people to enter years.